# Execute SQL Server stored procedure from Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I have an Oracle procedure that executes a SQL Server stored procedure. The SQL Server stored procedure executes one of three stored procedures based on an id field passed it from the Oracle  procedure.  Two of the stored procedure execute okay but the third does not.

The third stored procedure has several nested stored procedure calls.  It performs some calculations and then inserts to 3 different tables and then some additional calculations and updates one of the tables it just inserted to.  If I execute the stored procedure in SSMS it runs without issue.  When it is executed from Oracle side I get nothing.

Could this because of the nesting but because of the implicit commits I see it work using SMSS?  I tried doing a BEGIN Transaction in the starting stored procedure on  the MS SQL Server side and a commit at the end where it should return.  Still nothing.  I have Try and Catch blocks in the MS SQL stored procedures and don't receive any errors.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you could post some code. The explanation helps but a code block is worth a thousand words.

Comment: does "nothing" mean: no results, no errors, no rows inserted, no rows updated or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Does nothing means none of the inserts or updates show up in the tables. No error messages
As far as posting code; what specifically would you be interested in seeing?  There are 4 stored procedures which have 100s of lines of code each.